# How do I connect to a PostgreSQL database on Heroku server and use Chart.js?

Tags: php, html, database, postgresql, chart.js

I am looking to build a web application. I have deployed a database on Heroku using Postgresql and I do not see any demos or ways of connecting to the database unless it is mysql. Any help with actual code would be appreciated. I am brand new to all of this so don't judge me :).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a connection string from the Heroku `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

```
function pg_connection_string_from_database_url() {
  extract(parse_url($_ENV["DATABASE_URL"]));
  return "user=$user password=$pass host=$host dbname=" . substr($path, 1); # <- you may want to add sslmode=require there too
}
```

In order to establish a connection with the DB, you can use [`pg_connect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) which is a built-in function in PHP.

```
$conn_str = pg_connection_string_from_database_url();
$pg_conn = pg_connect($conn_str);
```

After successfully connecting to the DB, you can run the queries as you need.

```
$result = pg_query($pg_conn, "SELECT relname FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE schemaname='public'");
```

Few examples on how to use postgresql can be found [here in Official Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-queries.php)

Full code I used for this answer can be found [here](https://github.com/kch/heroku-php-pg/blob/master/index.php)